# .gitignore does not ignore untracked *.pb.go files

Tags: git

I can't figure out why, having updated my top-level `.gitignore` to ignore generated files with extension `pb.go`, I'm still seeing untracked files with that extension.

```
# > cat .gitignore
*.pb.go

# > git status
Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   .gitignore

Untracked files:
        some/path/filename.pb.go
```

Based on answers to similar questions on stackoverflow, I feel it's necessary to underline the fact that this pb.go file is untracked, it isn't in the git cache, as can be shown by

```
# > git rm -f --cached some/path/filename.pb.go
fatal: pathspec 'some/path/filename.pb.go' did not match any files
```

although it's entirely possible that generated file was at some point in the history, stored in git.

Comment: Hmm... weird... is there another .gitignore that has a rule about this file extension? Or checking inside the other config parts where you can ask to exclude stuff?

Comment: Does `**/*.pb.go` work?

Comment: That is a bit odd. Make sure `.gitignore` is a plain-text ASCII-only file, no UTF-8 BOM at the front, etc.

Comment: Have you tried committing the .gitignore and then re-running `git status`?

Comment: `git check-ignore -v some/path/filename.pb.go`

Comment: all good comments, thank you, I will try these suggestions.

Comment: @eftshift0 was right. There was .gitignore deep inside the repository that filtered * and later excluded !*.go. That resulted in *.pb.go not being excluded. Deleted that deep .gitignore and now everything's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was `.gitignore` deeper inside the repository with

```
* 
!*.go
```

That resulted in `*.pb.go` not being excluded.